# How To Ensure Each Method Runs In a Class?

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have a program that runs every 15 minutes to validate Sales Orders for my company.  Currently, there are about 65 "checks" every sales order must pass to make it through my program.  The Program uses a "permission list," which is essentially a SQL Table that stores the name of every method in my project with a True/False column for, "do you want this method to run."  I run a SQL Query for:

```
SELECT [MethodName] FROM [table] WHERE Permission='true'
```

which I then convert into collection type `List<string>`.  As I run through my Main, a method's name must exist in my List for that method to run.  This way, I control what methods are run through SQL, easy to update or turn off certain methods if need be, without updating the code base.  That way, if logic is ever off, or is not working as expected, I can easily turn the method off for the next 15 minute pickup of orders to check.

We are restructuring the way orders can be "kicked back" where before, if the orders failed even one method check, it would instantly end the remainder of the checks, notify a CSR what was wrong with the order, they change the order and resubmit it back to the app.

Now, we want all checks to run and we are generating a list of every error, to speed up the process of fixing the orders.  However, some methods are reliant on other methods passing, such as certain values already being checked if they're set to `null`, a bad value, improper zipcodes, dates, etc..

So, as an example, if I have a method that ensures a zipcode is exactly 5 or 9 digits, and I have a method that is validating a delivery address, it used to look like this:

```
//Make sure zipCode is 5 or 9 in length.
//kickback = true if zipCode is invalid.
checkZipCodeLength();
if(kickback == true)
     //try to confirm the order, which will fail due to kickback = true
     evaluateOrder(SalesOrder);
//Make sure delivery address is a valid address
//kickback = true, if address is invalid.
checkDeliveryAddress();
 if(kickback == true)    
     evaluateOrder(SalesOrder);
```

And so, the checks work in this type of style until all of them are run.  We want to remove the if statements and not kick anything back until all checks have happened, which means making checks rely independently, but be notified if a previous check that used to kickback the order has failed.

I am a bit lost how to update this, or even what collection type to use. Is using a SQL Table to make "rules" a good way to make these methods run?  Is there a better way to handle this? It almost feels like I am using a way around a real "check and balances" system and I am looking for suggestions on how to refactor the code for a better system of checking for methods to run, if there is one.

> Sorry for the wall of text, I am just trying to help people better understand the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"However, some methods are reliant on other methods passing, such as certain values already being checked if they're set to null, a bad value, improper zipcodes, dates, etc"*

This is not insurmountable if your tests are atomic: if you have a test that checks if a value is null, then subsequent tests should return `true` if the value is null, as they cannot determine it's validity.

For example:

```
public bool TestZipcodeIsNotNull(string zip) {
    if (zip == null)
          return false;
}

public bool TestZipcodeIsValid(string zip) {
     if (zip == null) 
          return true; // The other test will have failed!

     return (zip.Length == 5 || zip.Length == 9);
}
```

In this way the tests don't need to know about each other, and you have a lot of tests which each check one thing.

However I'm not sure how this would scale if your tests are complex and rely on several values..

Comment: Ah, I see.  most of my checks are just voids that adjust PublicVars.  That might be the way to go..